# How does angular-cli expose the ember-cli addon as ng?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js, angular-cli

Hi I am trying to create a different project specific to my team project and I would like to extend ember-cli the way angular-cli has and expose it under a different module name. I want to use ember-cli but not using ember command to drive it, I am hoping someone can explain how angular-cli exposed its ember-cli commands under ng.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/bin/ng